# Read XML result from SQL using FOR XML in Web API C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, webapi

I have a stored procedure that returns a table in XML format.At the end of
the script I have

```
for xml auto
```

I tried to read it as below

```
var data = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("exec spGetDataInXML").ToString();
```

But when I debug it data variable holds below value

```
exec spGetDataInXML
```

Answer (score 0):

You created the query but haven't executed it.
[Database.SqlQuery<T> returns
a IEnumerable<T> object that will execute the query when it is enumerated.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)
Try

```
var q = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("exec spGetDataInXML");
// execute the query
foreach (string s in q)
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: I want the full xml as a one string same as it's retrieved in SQL server.